# How to get time range of todays date with timezone in javascript and use it in mongo query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, momentjs

I want to run a query in mongo which will get data till 7:00 am, then 7 am to 11 am and then 12 pm to 4 pm of particular that day only. Now these time are stored in different timezone. So I want to know how get data from mongo.

I tried using momentJs to get the the time range but not able to get correct timezone.

```
var dayStart = moment().zone(timezone).startOf('day');
var now = moment().zone(timezone);
var duration = moment.duration(now - dayEnd);
```

and my mongo query is

```
db.CollectionName.find({"created_at": {
    '$gte': dayStart,
    '$lt': now
}});
```

I want the three result seperately that is till 7am, 7am-11am & 12pm-4pm. Any help please.

Comment: `moment().zone()` is deprecated so you don't want to use that approach. (https://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/zone/). Time zones and Offsets can be very tricky and depend on many variables: what timezone was used when writing the values in `created_at`, what time zone does the app run in, what time zone are users in, are they in multiple time zones? It helps to think of all the scenarios and user expectations, then let that guide how you approach the solution in code.

Comment: I am actually using Node4 so it has moment.zone. And timezone variable right now is for Asia/Kolkata. I am having problem in writing the right query and getting the result.

Comment: Ok! I advise against using deprecated features but I have provided some example to get you started and help you better understand how these features of moment work. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I would still advise against using `moment().zone()` - at the very least use `moment().utcOffset()` as it more clearly communicates the approach of the function. However, since you are using .zone() now I will share an example to get you started.

We assume the following:

- when a record is saved to your database, the `created_at` value defaults to UTC
- you are the only user of concern
- you are located in the Kolkata timezone and when you say 7am, you expect it to be relative to that location on earth

Using the zone feature, you would then need to a value of -330 to translate from UTC to Kolkata. (Since Kolkata is UTC+5:30, we must convert to minutes and then subtract that value 5 * 60 + 30 = 330.)

Given all of that, your values will be as follows:

```
var dayStart = moment().utc().zone(-330).startOf('day');
var now = moment().utc().zone(-330);
var duration = moment.duration(now.diff(dayStart)).as('minutes');
```

*you had a few typos in your example: `dayEnd` was an undefined variable, I assumed you meant to use dayStart. also, duration needs to use diff and an argument to format the output, I have used `minutes` for this example.*

You can test further and play around with this example:
https://jsfiddle.net/dusthaines/48wubezy/5/